# SSH key for Users of Windows 10

Tags: ssh-keys

I am trying to connect to an windows pc from an windows pc with SFTP&SSH, all OS with final release version. How can i export own SSH keys (each for 1 user) for remote pc users to login for key authentication. I tryed write these keys to "authorized_keys with WinSCP or with "#Copy-key" and "echo [openssh key] | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE.ssh\authorized_keys -Encoding ascii" command with known credentials of user on the remote pc. But the connection what i could create is the first one only where created public key in authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_key file . The seound key is rejected from server side

Comment: "ll OS with final release version" - This does not tell us anything help.  Please indicate what version of Windows 10 you have installed specifically.  Be sure you include what the current build number is.  This information is vital to answering your question.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro 1903 build:18362.329